# Find Indices of the pair of elements in the Array such that they add up to the Target value

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, java-stream

I want to find a `target` sum in an array by adding integers until it's reached, then return the **indexes** which add up to the target by using streams.

For example, if the provided array is `{1, 2, 3, 4}` and the `target` is `4`, the method should print out an array of int consisting of indexes `{0,2}`, but does not.

The code is as below:

```
public static int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
    IntStream.of(0, numbers.length - 1).boxed()
            .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(i , numbers.length - 1).boxed()
            .filter(j -> numbers[j] + numbers[i] == target)
            .flatMap(j -> Stream.of(new int[]{i , j}, new int[] {j,i})))
            .forEach(num -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num)));

    return numbers;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(twoSum(new int[]{1,2,5,1}, 4)));
}
```

Comment: By not adding `.boxed()`. `int[] b = Arrays.stream(numbers).filter((x -> num[finalI] + x == 4)).toArray();` Also, shouldn't that be `== target`?

Comment: Yes it should be target, i was just hardcoding the target for a time, but i also changed it to int[] b = Arrays.stream(numbers).filter((x -> num[finalI] + x == 4)).toArray(); which worked. But the return of this is an empty array for some reason

Comment: Please provide an example of the source array and the expected result. For instance, what should be the result for array `1, 4, 3, 0, 4, 1` and target sum `4`?

Comment: If the target sum was 4, it would return index of 0 and index of 2 because the sum of those elements is 4.

Comment: I was thinking of creating a Instream.range(0, number.length-1).boxed which could act as the initial for loop, then creating another instream that would compare all the indexes to the initial boxed stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but if you are using this code exactly, May it is because of the typo you have after foreach. You are initiating the input as `nu`, but printing it as `num`.

```
.forEach(num -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(num)));
```

Perhaps replacing this with what you have will solve the problem.

**EDIT**

Regarding more clarification over comments, It was realized that was an issue with given values and had nothing to do with Java stream API.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, let's describe the possible ways to address the problem:

- ***Brute-force approach***: iterate over the source array with a nested loop or using a nested stream (*reminder: stream is only a mean of iteration*) and check for every element whether there's a counterpart for in the array, so that together they constitute the given sum. Time complexity is **O(n^2)**.
- So-called **two-pointer approach**: sort the given array, define two variables that initially point to the first and the last indices, and then move the pointers. This algorithm could implemented using imperative style only. Time complexity is **O(n log n)** (because sorting required), which is much better nested loop/streams.
- Create a `Map` that will store all pair of elements that result into the target sum. The algorithm runs in a linear time **O(n)**. Only two iterations over the source array are required.

The solution below provides a stream-based implementation of the approach that utilizes a `Map`.

As the first step, we need to generate a *map* that will associate a value that required to be added to a particular element in order to obtain a `target` sum (a *key*) and the index of an array element (a *value*).

Then create a stream over the indices of the given array, filter out the first element that matches a *key* in the *map* and construct a *two-value* array based on it.

If a result was not found - return an empty array.

```
public static int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> sumMap = getSumMap(numbers, target);
    
    return IntStream.range(0, numbers.length)
        .filter(i -> sumMap.containsKey(numbers[i]))
        .mapToObj(i -> new int[]{i, sumMap.get(numbers[i])})
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(new int[0]);
}

public static Map<Integer, Integer> getSumMap(int[] numbers, int target) {
    rreturn IntStream.range(0, numbers.length)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            i -> target - numbers[i], //  a key - dif between target sum and a current element
            Function.identity(),      //  a value - index of the current element
            (left, right) -> left));  //  resolving duplicates
}
```

`main()` - demo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(twoSum(new int[]{1, 4, 3, 0, 4, 1}, 4)));
}
```

*Output*

```
[0, 2] // indices of the first pair of elements (1, 3) that can produce the sum of `4`
```

Comment: could you explain the purpose of Function.identity() in getsummap?

Comment: @bdunaway [`identity()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html#identity()) it returns the input that was passed as an argument without changes. It means the same as the following lambda `i -> i`. It's a common practice to use `Function.identity()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a for loop you can nest two `IntStreams` to produce the desired result (as I understand it).  This will return all pairs that sum to  the target value. This does not include elements of the array that added to themselves equal the target.  So for a target of `4`, `[2, 2]` is not included as a result

```
int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -2, -1, -3, -4, -5 };

int[][] array = twoSum(arr1, 4);

for (int[] a : array) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

prints

```
[1, 3]
[5, -1]
```

- First, stream a range of ints from 0 to one less than the array size.
- then use `boxed` to convert the int to an object.
- Then you `flatMap` (combine the nested streams into one) another `IntStream` starting with one more than the previous stream, but the full length of the array.
- still within the `flatMap` construct, and using the values of the `IntStreams` as the indices to the supplied array, filter away values that don't sum to the target, and create an array of the two numbers that did add up (this could also be replaced with the indices of the array if desired).
- Then return this array of arrays as a result.

```
public static int[][] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
    return IntStream.range(0, numbers.length - 1)
            .boxed()
            .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(i + 1, numbers.length)
                    .filter(k -> numbers[i] + numbers[k] == target)
                    .mapToObj(k -> new int[] { numbers[i],numbers[k] }))
            .toArray(int[][]::new);
}
```